# maintaining DNS resolution for connecting clients when using fresh app instances with fresh IPs

Tags: dns, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook for spinning up and building a brand new GNU/Linux box and installing vsftpd.

I have a client which needs to send a nightly file over SFTP. I have instructed to send to ftp.example.com.

I need to be able to very quickly run the playbook against any infrastructure provider (such as DigitalOcean, AWS, Rackspace etc) and without any change on the client end still receive the nightly file upload even if (as will be the case) the IP of the server has changed. So, one night the server may be on a DigitalOcean box in NewYork, the next on an AWS box in Ireland.

Now, obviously I could use a DNS name-server provider who has a good API to code against and reset the A-record as a stage of the playbook run. However, this will likely mean that until the client's DNS cache is flushed they will still be seeing ftp.example.com as the previous server.

So, how can I guarantee that this will work without any interaction on the part of the client.

Many thanks

Comment: Is there no reliable source to find out the IP address associated with `ftp.example.com`?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of DNS, you cant. Evan if you set a low TTL on the DNS records (time to live/expire) many DNS services cache short TTLs for up to 72 Hours.

My recommendation is not to have a infrastructure that requires constant changes in IP.

What may be a better solution is to use a distributed service like BitTorrentSync.

You could also host your own BIND server and ask your client to point his DNS at your BIND server, avoiding any third party DNS.

The real solution would be to stick keeping a persistant instance. If money is an issue, you can suspend your instance saving on compute in Amazon AWS